# Missing uppercase greek symbols in lualatex/memoir titles

Tags: fonts, luatex, memoir

I'd like to be able to include greek symbols in the \HepParticles macro from the hepparticles package in chapter/section/subsection titles in a memoir document.

I've included an MWE that compiles/renders fine with `pdflatex MWE.ltx; pdflatex MWE.ltx` but when compiled with `lualatex MWE.ltx; lualatex MWE.ltx` is missing the Lambda characters in the HepParticle macros titles in the body (fine in the ToC). This is using TexLive2017 on macOS 10.12

The problem appears to be with the uppercase greek characters, but I've not idea how to go about debugging the output I get during the compile.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
    Andy

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,openany]{memoir}

%%---
\maxsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\maxtocdepth{subsubsection}
%%---

%%---
\usepackage{hepparticles}
%%---

%%---
\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
  \mainmatter
    \chapter{\HepParticle{\Lambda}{1}{2} $\Lambda$}
    \section{\HepParticle{\Lambda}{3}{4} $\Lambda$}
    \subsection{\HepParticle{\Lambda}{5}{6} $\Lambda$}
    \subsubsection{\HepParticle{\Lambda}{7}{8} $\Lambda$}
  \backmatter
\end{document}
%%---
```

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) this is not related to the `memoir` class, it also seem to happen with the book class (using `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` and removing the irrelevant `\...matter` macros.

Comment: If you look closely it is always when used in a bold context there are issues. So I'm guessing that the font setup used by `hepparticles` does not work correctly with `lualatex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hepparticle` package has

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathup}{OT1}{\familydefault}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathup}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{bx}{n}
```

and of course the second line is completely wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hepparticles}

\SetMathAlphabet{\mathup}{bold}{OT1}{\familydefault}{bx}{n}

\begin{document}

\HepParticle{\Lambda}{1}{2} $\Lambda$

\bfseries

\HepParticle{\Lambda}{1}{2} $\Lambda$

\end{document}
```

Note that the package does `\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\boldmath}`, which is another bad error. I'd not use it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @daleif, @egreg!

I've added `\SetMathAlphabet{\mathup}{bold}{OT1}{\familydefault}{bx}{n}` to my preamble and it's resolved the issue.

Egreg, could you expand on why `\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\boldmath}` is problematic please?

Comment: @Andy probably because that should should be let to the user, not some random package.

Comment: @Andy I see no reason for making symbols bold: symbols are independent of the context. Besides, `\bfseries` is a command defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand`, so using `\g@addto@macro` is wrong also from a conceptual point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but there is an even smaller MWE. No issues with `pdflatex` but problems with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hepparticles}
\begin{document}
\HepParticle{\Lambda}{1}{2} $\Lambda$

\bfseries

\HepParticle{\Lambda}{1}{2} $\Lambda$
\end{document}
```